# can i mass update/insert report criteria

Tags: reporting, filters

we have built around 100+ reports and now I would like add a filter criteria to all these 100+ reports, is there a quick way to add the filter instead of going 1 by 1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Never done anything like that but reports are just like most other metadata types, which are defined by a XML specification file. So if you retrieve a report definition by any metadata API based tools, such as ANT (Salesforce Migration Tool), you get a XML file, and there's something like this that defines the filter criteria:

```
<filter>
    <criteriaItems>
        <column>Revenue__c.Fiscal_year__c</column>
        <operator>equals</operator>
        <value>2013</value>
    </criteriaItems>
    <criteriaItems>
        <column>STAGE_NAME</column>
        <operator>notEqual</operator>
        <value>Closed/Lost</value>
    </criteriaItems>
</filter>
```

So I guess you can put the new filter item in appropriate XML, then append it to each report XML's  section.  Once the editing is done and saved, just deploy the new definition files back to Salesforce and you're set.  You're going to need a good batch file editor though - on *nix it's pretty easy; not sure about Windows.

Comment: This is really easy if you're a Linux/Unix user (sed/awk/etc). For the rest of us, it'd be a bit more tedious, but certainly possible. How I'd do this is download the reports to the Force.com IDE, and use Find In Files > Replace All to mass update the reports.

Comment: Yes I suppose it's not that hard to do it with Replace All - just replace the closing tag, </filter>, with the new criteria added in, for instance, <criteriaItems><column>type</column><operator>equals</operator><value>Enterprise</value></criteriaItems></filter>